# Difference in Matlab results when using PCA() and PCACOV()

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, pca

Closest match I can get is to run:

```
  data=rand(100,10);  % data set
  [W,pc] = pca(cov(data));
```

then don't demean

```
  data2=data
  [W2, EvalueMatrix2] = eig(cov(data2));
  [W3, EvalueMatrix3] = svd(cov(data2));
```

In this case `W2` and `W3` agree and `W` is the transpose of them?

Still not clear why `W` should be the transpose of the other two?

As an extra check I use `pcacov`:

```
   [W4, EvalueMatrix4] = pcacov(cov(data2));
```

Again it agrees with `WE` and `W3` but is the transpose of `W`?

Comment: maybe `pca` computes the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix? [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/what-is-the-intuitive-relationship-between-svd-and-pca)

Comment: Did you try `eig` or `svd`?

Comment: It the link above it says that pca centers the data and uses svd (so some differences to pca result might be expected but these results are completely different?). It also says that the input should by a n*p matrix where n are the observation and p is the variables which doesn't suggest using a covariance matrix?

Comment: I tried with svd() it gives the same result as eig() apart from some are flipped positive and negative (which is no problem)

Comment: The edit to the question removed the explanation of the problem, which makes it less clear. The original steps taken in the code are removed, and the question is different now. Good practice is to open a second question in these cases, or append to the original question. The reason is that the question and the discussion it generates can be helpful to others who come across it later, but not if things are changed so drastically.

Answer (score 2):

The results are different because you're subtracting the mean of each row of the data matrix. Based on the way you're computing things, rows of the data matrix correspond to data points and columns correspond to dimensions (this is how the `pca()` function works too). With this setup, you should subtract the mean from each column, not row. This corresponds to 'centering' the data; the mean along each dimension is set to zero. Once you do this, results should be equivalent to `pca()`, up to sign flips.

**Edit to address edited question:**
Centering issue looks ok now. When you run the eigenvalue decomposition on the covariance matrix, remember to sort the eigenvectors in order of descending eigenvalues. This should match the output of `pcacov()`. When calling `pca()`, you have to pass it the data matrix, not the covariance matrix.

Comment: I realise it was becoming cluttered so I've simplified. Still strikes me as odd that pca(cov(data))  and pcacpv(cov(data) ) should be diferent.

Comment: Edited the answer to address this